# Android: Promote to select my live-wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Hi I found this nice code that promote the user to set my wallpaper:

```
public void requestWallpaperChange() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
  intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
    new ComponentName(this, MyWallpaperService.class));
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

However it is only available from API 16, how do I achieve this on older versions?

Answer (score 1):

You can't jump directly to your live wallpaper but can open up the picker before API level 16.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
{
    intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
    intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(this, GLWallpaperService.class));
}   
else
{
    intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
}   

startActivity(intent);
```